# What are the best strategies to deal with multicollinear variables?

Tags: regression, correlation, multicollinearity

I have a time-series dataset that has 63 features. The predictions are coming out to be extensively wrong; specifically because of the high collinearity among some of the variables according to this correlation matrix:

[image: collinearity plot]

My question is how do variables that have collinearity shown as blue squares affect ML models other than the red ones that of course inflate the variance of the response variable and do they need to b treated the same as the red squares?

Comment: Colinearity $\neq$ correlation. Please edit your question to clarify which you are talking about. I presume you mean correlation, because there is no such thing as negative colinearity.

Answer (score 3):

Whether the **correlation** is positive or negative has nothing to do with the severity of nor the way you treat **colinearity**.

Correlation is the extent to which one variable changes when the other does. Colinearity is when two *or more* variables are a linear combination of one another.

If there is perfect colinearity, then a variable can be completely explained as a linear combination of other variables.

Consider the simple example $A=-B$:

- These are perfectly *negatively* correlated;
- $A$ and $B$ are perfectly colinear.

To give an example of three perfectly colinear variables (but not perfectly positively *or* negatively correlated):

$A+B+C=1$

Adding all three of these variables to a regression model would cause colinearity issues, but this has little to do with their pairwise correlations.

Comment: so a regression model like ridge that addresses multicollinearity will not actively generate uncorrelated regression coefficient estimates? is there a textbook source that explains this difference between correlation and collinearity more? also, between the two, which should be tuned in order to promote **diversity** amongst estimates?

Answer (score 0):

From a regression perspective, sever multicollinearity between features can cause your standard errors to become unstable. For continuous features, one usually computes the Pearson correlation and excludes predictors above some prespecified cutoff. There are a number of cutoffs that you can use; there's no hard and fast rule for what value to use as a cutoff.

For predictive modelling, the variable which is the least predictive is removed. To keep it simple, you could just look at univariate measures of the predictive strength a variable has with the response.

That said, if predictive performance is your goal (as is generally the case with machine learning), using [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) to condense your predictor set seems like a reasonable idea. I believe the literature you're referring to means the magnitude of the correlation. That is, the absolute value of the Pearson correlation. That's why they never mention 'negative correlation', as you say.

Comment: Not just standard errors, the estimates become unstable! Pearson correlation is a really poor diagnostic for collinearity, as you'd be looking only at pairwise correlations. You should use the condition number instead.

Comment: Good point! Assessment by Pearson correlation is rudimentary at best in this case. A simple, but dirty check. Nonetheless, a good point :)